# monodroid for android service

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I want to use monodroid to develop an android application which runs as a background service.

Can anyone provide a pointer to sample code on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a basic service example in one of my [samples on GitHub](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/tree/master/MonoDroid/MonoDroidSamples/MonoDroidSamples/DemoActivities/Services). The basic idea is that you define a class that extends `Service` and decorate it with the Service attribute in order to generate the appropriate configuration in AndroidManifest.xml (you could optionally do that yourself, but you should rarely need to).

```
[Service]
public class MusicService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        // ...
    }

    public override void OnStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStart(intent, startId);

        // ...
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the override - public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId) ?

Comment: Also, there are some other steps for configuring your service, depending on your needs.  See http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html it is absolutely crucial.

Comment: For anyone who decides to run their service in a seperate process, you should see http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Creating-service-in-a-new-process-td5710256.html and comment #4 at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=763